# Мне нужно вывести числа от 0 до 255 и перевести их в двоичную систему

Tags: c

Мне нужно вывести числа от 0 до 255 и перевести их в двоичную систему. Я написал такой замечательный код:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i<=255){
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
          if(i & 0x80){
              printf("1");
          }
          else{
              printf("0");
          }
        i <<= 1;
      }
      i=i+1;
      printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

у меня выводит только два числа [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что должно происходить в цикле ``for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)``?

Answer (score 3):

Вы делаете операции над `i` которая одновременно является шаблоном для чисел и параметром внешнего цикла.
Т.е. после прохождения внутреннего цикла чему будет равна `i`? Правильно - нулю, а не следующему числу из цикла.

```
int i = 0;
while(i<=255)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) 
   {
       i <<= 1;
   }
   i = i+1;
}
```

Сделайте внешний цикл отдельно от `i` - переменной над которой вы проводите операцию побитового сдвига.

```
for (int k = 0; k <= 255; k++) 
{
   int i = k;
   for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) 
   {
       i <<= 1;
   }
}
```